# Setting & Getting Page specific variables DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm very much new to DNN. using DNN 9 for my new project. it looks very simple.

I need to set a class to BODY tag so can have different menu styling.

I wanna know how can I set this class for a specific page and also get its value on a specific template

Thanks,

-Naveed

Comment: You cannot set the body class in the Page Settings.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Provide a little more detail and we can likely point you in the right direction on how to do things within DNN